# How to get a store from a Promise in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I'm new in svelte-town and am trying to figure out how to get a promise out of a store, and into an async init function which would then be waited upon with <#await> , so far the theory works (note I am brand new to Svelte, so my theory is most likely wrong).
My problem is the components I get back are stores so in the code they are referenced as {$component}, which the REPL doesn't really like.

The error message reads :

> Stores must be declared at the top level of the component (this may change in a future version of Svelte)

So my question is How do I go around that?
[This simple REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b5cd07ebed24423ea465c1ce1e7f9f02?version=3.48.0) shows what I mean.

For those like me, who dont really want to click on stuff here's the code.

```
<script>
async function init(data){
    await data
    //do amazing stuff here 
    return { list1: readable_store1, list2:readable_store2}
}</script>
<#await>
{:then {list1,list2}}
<ul> {#each $list1 as list} <li/>{list} </ul>
```

Comment: What is the point of that being a store in the first place?

Comment: Well its a data source that is piled every few minutes to check for new stuff. I just did the repl as simple as possible to focus more on the problem instead of pushing everything there

Comment: State is reactive by default, there usually has to be a good reason for using a store. It's all very unclear; what does the async function actually do? If it is fetching data, why not return that directly without a store? If you really do need a store, why not declare it at the top and *update it asynchronously*?

Comment: As I said, I'm brand new to svelte, I thought about separation of concerns .. this is the actual thing doing https://svelte.dev/repl/293b8f17d3014c75a5a4623abfdc30aa?version=4.2.0

Comment: You've got it right already in your second take, with `getData().then(v => set(v))`, that's how you connect a promise to a store. The mind model being, promise and store are both box objects that wrap around the real value, you most likely just need one. Regardless of svelte's limitation, there's really no point to return a store from a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the store or use the await.  No need to do both.  If you are looking to re-fetch/update the data, as you said, then using `{#await}` (which has a bracket typo in your example), is going to stop showing the data and instead show your loading message each time you refetch.  To avoid this, using a store...

Custom store with your fetch built in:

```html
<script>
  import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

  const createStore = () => {
    const {subscribe, set, update} = writable({list1: [], list2: []});

    return {
      subscribe,
      getList1: async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://example.com/api/list1');
        const data = await response.json().then((data) => data);
        update((currentValue) => {
          currentValue.list1 = [...currentValue.list1, ...data];
          return currentValue;
        }); // update if you are tacking on data
      },
      getList2: async () => {
        const response = await fetch('https://example.com/api/list2');
        const data = await response.json().then((data) => data);
        set((currentValue) => {
          currentValue.list2 = [...currentValue.list2, ...data];
          return currentValue;
        }); // set if you are replacing data
      },
    }
  }

  const store = createStore();
</script>

<ul>
  {#each $store.list1 as item}
    <li>{item}</li>
  {/each}
  {#each $store.list2 as item}
    <li>{item}</li>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

Normal writable store with fetch call elsewhere:

```
<script>
  import {writable} from 'svelte/store';
  import {onMount} from 'svelte';

  let loading = false;
  const store = writable({
    list1: [],
    list2: []
  });

  const getLists = async () => {
    const list1Promise = fetch('https://example.com/api/list1').then(async(r) => await r.json()).then((r) => $store.list1 = [...$store.list1, ...r]);
    const list2Promise = fetch('https://example.com/api/list2').then(async(r) => await r.json()).then((r) => $store.list2 = r);
  }

  onMount(() => {
    getLists();
  });
</script>

<ul>
  {#each $store.list1 as item}
  <li>{item}</li>
  {/each}
  {#each $store.list2 as item}
  <li>{item}</li>
  {/each}
</ul>
```